# How can I tell if I broke my GPIOs?

Tags: gpio

I was messing around with some lighting, then everything went black.  My pi is still working fine, but I can't get the lights to turn on anymore.

I'm pretty sure this indicates I broke something... or perhaps something needs to be reset.

Is there a simple way to check if I have broken my GPIOs?

Answer (score 2):

The wiringPi library has the pintest utility.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) has the [gpiotest](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing) utility.

Both will check basic GPIO functionality.  My gpiotest is slightly more thorough.

A run of gpiotest with all gpios okay.

```
This program checks the Pi's (user) gpios.

The program reads and writes all the gpios.  Make sure NOTHING
is connected to the gpios during this test.

The program uses the pigpio daemon which must be running.

To start the daemon use the command sudo pigpiod.

Press the ENTER key to continue or ctrl-C to abort...

Testing...
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None
```

A run of gpiotest showing failed gpios.

```
This program checks the Pi's (user) gpios.

The program reads and writes all the gpios. Make sure NOTHING
is connected to the gpios during this test.

The program uses the pigpio daemon which must be running.

To start the daemon use the command sudo pigpiod.

Press the ENTER key to continue or ctrl-C to abort...

Testing...
Write 1 to gpio 17 failed.
Pull up on gpio 17 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 18 failed.
Pull up on gpio 18 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 23 failed.
Pull down on gpio 23 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 24 failed.
Pull down on gpio 24 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 27 failed.
Pull up on gpio 27 failed.
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
Failed user gpios: 17 18 23 24 27
```